# Absolute URL in an include inside a function with MAMP

Tags: php

I have a function to make the echoes of the code, so I don't have to repeat it everytime:

```
function echo_snippets($connection, $query, $snippet, $variable_1, $variable_2, $variable_3, $variable_4, $variable_5, $variable_5){
    $result = $connection->query("CALL $query");
    if($result){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            include 'includes/snippets/'.$snippet.'';
        }
        $result->close();
        $connection->next_result();
    }
}
```

Then I call the function from the pages:

```
<?php
    echo_snippets($connection,'index_php_Query_one()', 'echo_things.php', '', '', '', '', '', ''); ?>
    // Empty spaces are for variables I can use sometimes.
?>
```

And then in the included file in /includes/snippets/echo_things.php I have the variables and the echo:

```
<?php
    $first_thing = $row-> first_thing;
    $second_thing = $row-> second_thing;
    echo '<div>This is the first_thing: '.$first_thing.' 
    and the second_thing:'.$second_thing.'</div>';
?>
```

Everything works. But I have a problem with the url of the include inside the function. I can not use relative url because then I can not call the function from inside a directory. I am working in local directory with MAMP, and for some reason it doesn't accept the absolute address:

```
include 'http://localhost:8888/includes/snippets/'.$snippet.'';
```

The only solution I found was to pass the absolute url when calling the function

```
    echo_snippets($connection,'index_php_Query_one()', '../includes/snippets/echo_things.php', '', '', '', '', '', ''); ?>
```

But I was wondering it there was a way to give an absolute url to the function.

A.

Comment: why you cant use getcwd() to get current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
getcwd()
```

This will give:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/your_project_dir
```